# Fill the value forward until some condition satisfied

Tags: r

```
      id cate  result
 1     1 yes       1
 2     1 yes      NA
 3     1 no       NA
 4     2 no       NA
 5     2 yes       1
 6     2 yes      NA
 7     2 no       NA
 8     3 no       NA
 9     3 yes      NA
10     3 no       NA
11     3 yes       1
12     3 yes      NA
13     3 no       NA
14     3 yes      NA
15     4 yes       1
16     4 yes      NA
17     4 yes      NA
18     4 no       NA
19     4 no       NA
```

I want to fill the value of the `result` (1) forward up to the first no of the `cate` variable.

I try it using the code

```
library(tidyverse)
d2 <- d %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(result, .direction = 'down')
```

But the desired output is

```
      id cate  result
 1     1 yes       1
 2     1 yes       1
 3     1 no        1
 4     2 no       NA
 5     2 yes       1
 6     2 yes       1
 7     2 no        1
 8     3 no       NA
 9     3 yes      NA
10     3 no       NA
11     3 yes       1
12     3 yes       1
13     3 no        1
14     3 yes      NA
15     4 yes       1
16     4 yes       1
17     4 yes       1
18     4 no        1
19     4 no       NA
```

I also used the code for the following sample data,

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4), stat=c('sup','unsup','unsup', 'sup', 
                                                        'unsup','unsup','unsup','unsup','sup', 'sup','unsup','unsup','sup', 'sup','unsup','unsup'),
                  ind=c(NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA, NA,NA,1,NA))
```

and the Expected output

```
  id  stat ind
  1   1   sup  NA
  2   1 unsup   1
  3   1 unsup   1
  4   1   sup   1
  5   2 unsup   1
  6   2 unsup   1
  7   2 unsup   1
  8   2 unsup   1
  9   2   sup   1
  10  3   sup  NA
  11  3 unsup   1
  12  3 unsup   1
  13  4   sup  NA
  14  4   sup  NA
  15  4 unsup   1
  16  4 unsup   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution uses a cumulative sum and lead-lag logic. The first clause before the central `|` covers everything except the NA in row 14, and the second clause fills this gap.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), cate = c("yes", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", 
"yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", 
"yes", "yes", "no", "no"), result = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 

df %>%
  group_by(key_no = cumsum((cate == "no" & !is.na(lag(cate)) & lag(cate) == "no") |
                             (cate == "yes" & row_number() > 2 & lag(cate) == "no"& lag(cate, n = 2) == "yes"))) %>%
  fill(result, .direction = "down") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-key_no)
```

The output:

```r
# # A tibble: 19 × 3
#       id cate  result
#    <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
#  1     1 yes        1
#  2     1 yes        1
#  3     1 no         1
#  4     2 no        NA
#  5     2 yes        1
#  6     2 yes        1
#  7     2 no         1
#  8     3 no        NA
#  9     3 yes       NA
# 10     3 no        NA
# 11     3 yes        1
# 12     3 yes        1
# 13     3 no         1
# 14     3 yes       NA
# 15     4 yes        1
# 16     4 yes        1
# 17     4 yes        1
# 18     4 no         1
# 19     4 no        NA
```

Comment: Please send the sample data with dput(), and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I also edited the question based on the sample data which is not worked for me with the same code you provided, #dcsuka. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I believe I fixed it.

Comment: ```dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4), stat=c('sup','unsup','unsup', 'sup', 'unsup','unsup','unsup','unsup','sup', 'sup','unsup','unsup','sup', 'sup','unsup','unsup'), ind=c(NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA, NA,NA,1,NA))```    Sorry this is the sample data

Comment: What is the expected output? Should there be any differences?

Comment: I use the same code, i.e.  ```dat %>% group_by(key=cumsum((stat=="sup"&lag(stat)=='sup')|
                              (stat == "unsup" & row_number() > 2 & 
                                 lag(stat) == "sup"& lag(stat, n = 2) == "unsup"))) %>% 
  fill(ind, .direction = "down")%>%  ungroup()``` . But the variable key produces all impty values rather than cumulative sum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246887/discussion-between-yebelay-berehan-and-dcsuka).

Answer (score 2):

A not very *dplyr*-y solution, but it seems to work.
I'm `match`-ing the first `1`, then `match`ing the first `"no"` after a `1`, then replacing the values in `result` within this range with a `1`:

```
dat %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(
    result = {
        ones = match(1, result)
        nos  = match("no", tail(cate, -ones)) + ones
        replace(result, seq(ones,nos), 1)
    }    
    )

## A tibble: 19 x 3
## Groups:   id [4]
#      id cate  result
#   <int> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1     1 yes        1
# 2     1 yes        1
# 3     1 no         1
# 4     2 no        NA
# 5     2 yes        1
# 6     2 yes        1
# 7     2 no         1
# 8     3 no        NA
# 9     3 yes       NA
#10     3 no        NA
#11     3 yes        1
#12     3 yes        1
#13     3 no         1
#14     3 yes       NA
#15     4 yes        1
#16     4 yes        1
#17     4 yes        1
#18     4 no         1
#19     4 no        NA
```

Comment: In `ones = match(1, result)`, what will be if all values in group id are missing? Based on the answer the group must have at least 1 non missing value of `result`?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::reduce`:

```r
library(purrr)

reduce(2:nrow(df), ~ {
  if (is.na(.x[.y, 3]) & !is.na(.x[.y-1, 3]) & .x[.y-1, 2] != "no") 
    .x[.y, 3] <- .x[.y-1, 3]
  .x}, .init = df)

#>    id cate result
#> 1   1  yes      1
#> 2   1  yes      1
#> 3   1   no      1
#> 4   2   no     NA
#> 5   2  yes      1
#> 6   2  yes      1
#> 7   2   no      1
#> 8   3   no     NA
#> 9   3  yes     NA
#> 10  3   no     NA
#> 11  3  yes      1
#> 12  3  yes      1
#> 13  3   no      1
#> 14  3  yes     NA
#> 15  4  yes      1
#> 16  4  yes      1
#> 17  4  yes      1
#> 18  4   no      1
#> 19  4   no     NA
```